# Vue propsData not updating dynamically

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I've been struggling with this issue for hours:
I've instantiated dynamically a child vue component inside a parent component, and passed in propsData some of the parent's data. The dynamically created child's properties doesn't seem to update when the parent updates.

Please check the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/ryozlqvk8m) I created for a better understanding (forked from chinchang's example)

As you can see, I'm instantiating Button components both dynamically and statically. The color of the button depends on the type property. I pass the parent's data(the type attribute) as props both to the dynamically and statically created instances. When you insert a new button, by clicking the 'Click to insert' button, a new Button is created, using the parent's current type. After the click event, I switch the parent's type attribute. As you can see the statically created button instance (on the top on the page) changes color, but the dynamically instantiated ones remain the same.

Could you point out my mistake please and help to find a solution?

Thanks,
Ábel

Comment: I get a row of alternating colored buttons. Are you expecting them all to change color each time a new one is inserted?

Comment: Yes I do, they should all be the same type based on the type attribute defined in the parent, so they should all switch color on every click. Just like the statically instantiated Hello button does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#propsData):

> Pass props to an instance during its creation. This is primarily
> intended to make unit testing easier.

Setting `propsData` does not create a parent-child relationship. It simply provides (non-reactive) data to the component. In short, you've chosen a not-very-Vue approach. You shouldn't be concerned with creating components, you should have data items in your viewmodel that Vue then creates components for.

```
  export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: { Button },
    data(){
      return {
        type: 'secondary',
        buttons: []
      };
    },
    methods: {
      onClick() {
        this.buttons.push(true);
        if(this.type === 'primary'){
          this.type = 'secondary';
        } else {
          this.type = 'primary';
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

and

```
  <div ref="container">
    <button @click="onClick">Click to insert</button>
    <Button v-for="b in buttons" :type="type">Click me!</Button>
  </div>
```

[Fixed demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/9y4lynl2lr)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so it won't work this way. My example does not show the real-life usecase I'm struggling with, only  intended to show that propsData is not reactive. 
In my project I'd like to add custom labels/badges to different (dynamic) Vue components. To achieve this, I created a mixin that instantiates a LabelComponent based on the attributes of the component it's mixed with, and appends the label element to the components $el.
This way I don't have to include and wire a <label-component> in every component it is needed, I only have to use the mixin
Is there maybe a better way?

Comment: That is worth asking a new question for. A good answer would require particulars about how you want things to work.