# Vue reactive props on programmatic component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Given a component:

```
Vue.component('my-comp', {
  props: ['input'],
  watch: { input: function(){...} },
});
```

What is the programmatic method for the following?

```
<my-comp :input="map[key]"></my-comp> map[key] change triggers watch
```

I have tried:

```
new (Vue.component('my-comp'))({
  propsData: { input:map[key] }, // map[key] change doesn't trigger watch
});
```

The context for this is inserting zero-to-many components into markdown-generated HTML. I call `.$mount()` for each component, and move its node with a native DOM `replaceChild()` call when markdown is re-rendered. See also [Vue components in user-defined markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49139819/vue-components-in-user-defined-markdown)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vue propsData not updating dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48662160/vue-propsdata-not-updating-dynamically)

Comment: The answer to that Q didn't appear to solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If prop input is a primitive value, we have to manipulate the component with `child.$props.input = x` as Roy J suggests, but in this case we need `input = map[key]`. Hence this solution:

```
Vue.component('my-comp', {
  props: ['map','key'],
  computed: { input: function() { return this.map[this.key] } },
  watch: { input: function(a, b) {...} }, // triggered on map[key] change
});

new (Vue.component('my-comp'))({
  propsData: { map:theMap, key:theKey }, // theMap must be reactive
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A [render function](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html) is the programmatic means of creating and inserting a component. Using `new` with `propsData` is [primarily for unit testing](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#propsData), where the component will not necessarily have a Vue instance as a parent.

`$mount` doesn't establish a parent-child relationship, it just mounts the component free-standing to the DOM. You will need to set up the parent-child props management.

```js
Vue.component('my-comp', {
  template: '<div>{{ input }}</div>',
  props: ['input']
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    thingy: 5,
    child: null
  },
  created() {
    this.child = new(Vue.component('my-comp'))({
      propsData: {
        input: this.thingy
      }
    });
    this.$watch('thingy', (newValue) => this.child.$props.input = newValue);
    setInterval(() => ++this.thingy, 2000);
  },
  mounted() {
    this.child.$mount(this.$el);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
```

Comment: I call `$mount()` for components, so they do get rendered. Does `child.$props.input = x` force re-rendering?

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I've posted a second method.